# My function returns empty list while I try to import data from csv file

Tags: python, list, function, csv

I want to create a function to search for a composer by name in the given dataset.
and return a list of the appropriate “BL record IDs” related to one composer. Below is my code, however, after running it I get an empty list...

```
def ComposerSearch(filename, composer_column, name_search, record_id):
     import csv

     ids_list = []

     with open(filename, newline = '', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
           if name_search in row[composer_column] and record_id in row[composer_column]:
             ids_list.append(row[record_id])

     return ids_list

name_search = input("Enter Composer's name: ")
ComposerSearch('bl_printed_music_500.csv', 'Composer', name_search, 'BL record ID')
```

Comment: So if i understand the name and the record is is in the same row and column?

Comment: Probably you're passing incorrectly the filename, and reader is empty, try to run line by line to debug where it's failling

Comment: Can you make your question reproducible by adding two things: give us a minimal CSV data set to test with, having two or three records in it, and replace the call to `input()` by a hard coded query we can just cut and paste? It'll be a lot easier to test this way and see what's happening.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I have figured it out! The answer is below

Answer (score 0):

```
    def ComposerSearch(filename, composer_column, name_search, record_id):
    import csv

    ids_list = []

    with open(filename, newline = '', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
  if name_search in row[composer_column]:
    ids_list.append(row[record_id])
  
  return ids_list
 
name_search = input("Enter Composer's name: ")
ComposerSearch('bl_printed_music_500.csv', 'Composer', name_search, 'BL record ID')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).